# mutliline text in backstage template parameter is keeping firstline not to aligned/indent

Tags: spotify, backstage

I am using multiline text backstage template parameter

```
        environments:
          title: Text area input
          type: string
          description: Insert your multi line string
          ui:widget: textarea
          ui:options:
            rows: 20
          ui:help: 'Hint: Provide environments with optional resources like "cpu" and "memory". Example format: \nqa-us-east-1:\n  resources:\n    cpu: 30\n    memory: 20Gi' 
          ui:placeholder: 'Enter your environments here...'
```

The rendered text as

```
environments:qa-us-east-1:
  xxx-us-east-1:
    cpu: 1
    mem: 1G
  xxx-us-west-2:
  xxx-us-east-1:
   loadbalancers: 1
  xxx-us-west-2:
```

But I want it as

```
  qa-us-east-1:
  xxx-us-east-1:
    cpu: 1
    mem: 1G
  xxx-us-west-2:
  xxx-us-east-1:
    loadbalancers: 1
  xxx-us-west-2:
```

Is there better type to support it with yaml formatting text